# Logical comparison of a symmetric matrix and its transpose

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, transpose

I was trying to test numerically if the multiplication of a matrix and its transpose really generates a symmetric square matrix.

Below is the code I used:

```
mat = np.array([[1,2,3],[1,0,1],[1,1,1],[2,3,5]])
mat2 = np.linalg.inv(np.matmul(np.transpose(mat),mat))
mat2
array([[ 1.42857143,  0.42857143, -0.85714286],
   [ 0.42857143,  1.92857143, -1.35714286],
   [-0.85714286, -1.35714286,  1.21428571]])
```

mat2 appears to be symmetric.

However, the result of the below code made me confused:

```
np.transpose(mat2) == mat2
array([[ True, False, False],
   [False,  True, False],
   [False, False,  True]])
```

But when I did the same procedure with mat, the result was as I expected:

```
np.transpose(np.matmul(np.transpose(mat),mat)) == np.matmul(np.transpose(mat),mat)
array([[ True,  True,  True],
   [ True,  True,  True],
   [ True,  True,  True]])
```

Is this related a computational issue? If then, how can I show that the off-diagonal elements are identical?

Answer (score 2):

Comparing `mat` and `mat.T`, you're comparing integers to integers and there's no problem.

`mat2` is floating point, which is prone to subtle errors. When you print out `mat2`, you're seeing the truncated version of the full digits. Look at the *difference* between `mat2` and `mat2.T`:

```
>>> mat2 - mat2.T
array([[ 0.00000000e+00,  1.11022302e-16, -1.11022302e-16],
       [-1.11022302e-16,  0.00000000e+00,  2.22044605e-16],
       [ 1.11022302e-16, -2.22044605e-16,  0.00000000e+00]])
```

The differences are on the order of `0.0000000000000001`, meaning that they're equal "for all intents an purposes" but not equal exactly. There are two places to go from here. You can either accept that numerical precision is limited and use something like `numpy.allclose` for your equality tests, which allows for some small errors:

```
>>> np.allclose(mat2, mat2.T)
True
```

Or, if you really insist on your matrices being symmetric, you can enforce it with something like this:

```
>>> mat3 = (mat2 + mat2.T)/2
>>> mat3 == mat3.T
array([[ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True]])
```

Comment: I understand there is numerical error while computing float numbers. But in my knowledge taking transpose of a matrix is just switching the counterparts of off-diagonal elements. Since no numerical computation is done, mat2[0,1] and mat2.T[1,0] should be the same. What do you think?

Comment: The floating point error shows up when you do `np.linalg.inv`, not when you take the transpose.